# Parsing logs with regex

Tags: java, regex, logging, jboss

I'm trying to parse JBoss logs to retreive error messages and such. 
This is the pattern that I am using:
`([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9][0-9]) .*? ((?:ERROR .*? .*?|WARN  .*? .*?)) (.*? .* (?!at).*? .*\sjava.*)`

The `*\sjava.*` part is supposed to retreive NullPointer exceptions in the next line.

When i test it on http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/ (with UNIX_LINES option checked), everything works fine. However, when i use the same pattern in java code, nothing is outputed and my program freezes.
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9][0-9]) .*? ((?:ERROR .*? .*?|WARN  .*? .*?)) (.*? .* (?!at).*? .*\\sjava.*)", Pattern.UNIX_LINES);`

Everything also works fine when i remove `\sjava.*` from the pattern.

This is a sample from the log file:

> `2011-06-08 03:28:48,408 INFO 
>   [STDOUT]
>   (http-exxample.com%2F10.8.238.48-8180-7)
>   2011-06-08 03:28:48,403 WARN 
>   [http-example.com%2F10.8.238.48-8180-7]
>   interceptors.WebFault
>   (WebFault.java:125)     - Exception occurred while writing fault.`
>
> `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Everything is in a single line except `java.lang.NullPinterException`.

Does java require any special way of escaping `\s` (whitespaces)?

Comment: Give an example of the log. You might have a stray space in the regex

Answer (score 0):

No - you've escaped `\s` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression makes very heavy greedy matches. I think you should be a bit less greedy with your various

```
.*
```

Depending on the size of your log files, they tend to be very CPU-intensive... It's hard to say without example logs, though, how you could improve the regex

Answer (score 0):

You may expect **zero or more space characters**. Try `\\s*java.*`

---

**EDIT**:
Use [DOTALL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) Pattern.

```
    String s = "2011-06-08 03:28:48,403 WARN [http-example.com%2F10.8.238.48-8180-7] interceptors.WebFault (WebFault.java:125) "
      + "- Exception occurred while writing fault."
      + "\n\n  java.lang.NullPointerException\n";
    System.out.println(s.matches("(?s)([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9][0-9]) .*? "
      + "((?:ERROR .*? .*?|WARN .*? .*?)) (.*? .* (?!at).*? .*\\sjava.*[\n])"));
```

Comment: Tried, program still freezes.